# Custom Twig filter not found when called

Tags: php, symfony, filter, twig

I'm trying to create my own Twig filter. I followed this tuto [Symfony Official Book](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).
But I get this error `The filter "avatar" does not exist in src/Acme/Bundle/StoryBundle/Resources/views/Story/storyList.html.twig`

Here is my AvatarExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AvatarExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {

        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('avatar', array($this, 'avatar')),
        );

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'avatar_extension';
    }

    public function avatar($user)
    {
        if ($user->getPicture() && $user->getPicture() != '') {
            return $user->getPicture();
        } else {
            return '/images/default-avatar.jpg';
        }
    }
}
```

And my AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
    app.twig.avatar_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AvatarExtension
        tags:
        – { name: twig.extension }
```

The template using the filter is not in the same bundle as the Twig extension, but since it is a service, it shouldn't be a problem.
Here is how I call it : `{{ story.author|avatar }}`

Do you have any idea what the problem might be ?

EDIT

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
      uploadTmpDir: %upload.tmp.relative.dir%
```

Comment: Is the services.yml indented like that? If so you need to indent the `- { name: twig.extension }` another 4 spaces.

Comment: Yep, looks strange that your services.yml file is compiling, i thought you'd get a "You cannot define a sequence item when in a mapping" exception.

Comment: The services.yml file is properly indented. Indentation broke when I posted it here

Comment: try clearing your cache

Comment: check the service is correctly loaded by `php app/console container:debug|grep 'app.twig.avatar_extension'` then check that you haven't already registered another twig extension with the same name. Hope this help.

Comment: In a standard installation of a symfony2.6 project, the app bundle don't have the dependency injection manager class, if is so you must follow [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) guide. Let me know.

Comment: @Matteo the command issued this : `app.twig.avatar_extension                                          AppBundle\Twig\AvatarExtension`

I have other services registered in the AppBundle, and it works fine

@DerickF I tried clearing my cache but I still got the problem

Comment: All looks ok, very strange...

Comment: As workaround you can try to use the [default twig filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html) as follow: `{{ story.author.picture |default('/images/default-avatar.jpg') }}`

Comment: you have the twig section in your `config.yml` files? can you post it?

Comment: I edited the original post with the twig config in config.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. Here is the services.yml

```
app.twig.avatar_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AvatarExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

And here is the ExtensionClass:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AvatarExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('avatar', array($this, 'avatarFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function avatarFilter($user)
    {
        if ($user->getPicture() && $user->getPicture() != '') {
            return $user->getPicture();
        } else {
            return '/images/default-avatar.jpg';
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'avatar_extension';
    }
}
```

I guess the function name must have the Filter suffix